# How to use pod hostname in subPathExpr filed in volume for kind as Deployment in kubernetes v1.13.0

Tags: kubernetes

Not able to use subPathExpr or subPath in volume when kind is Deployment.

Tried using subpath giving some env variable, but is was not creating the folder with value, it is getting created with ${xyz}

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: abc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: abc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: abc
    spec:
        env:
        - name: NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/logs
          name: abc
          subPath: $(NAME)
      volumes:
      - name: abc
        hostPath:
          path: /opt/abc
          type: Directory
```

i want to create the volume directory with pod hostname, but not able to create

example : 
if pod name is xyzservice-3216544-fv4

i want to create the volume directory like /opt/abc/xyzservice-3216544-fv4

Answer (score 2):

What's your Kubernetes Cluster Version?
**[Using subPath with expanded environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath-with-expanded-environment-variables)** is a new FEATURE(alpha) in v1.14

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Version i am using is 1.13, link you provided will be support for kind: Pod, i need for kind: Deployment

Comment: Pod is K8S's smallest workload unit,Deployment and ReplicaSet are K8S's workload Controller. When you create a `Deployment`, K8S will create Deployment、ReplicaSet and Pods for you, and the control relation is `pods`  controlled by `ReplicaSet`; `ReplicaSet` controlled by `Deployment`。pod is deployment's Subset, and pod's context is defined with .spec.spec in Deployment yaml file.

Comment: I suggest you upgrade the Kubernetes cluster to v1.14 and enable the alpha function, and try again.